# How to delete sqlite database of my application in android mobile manually

Tags: android, sqlite, mobile

After deploying my application into android mobile,at starting the database is getting created.
I do want to delete database tables in mobile.How to do that in mobile..

Comment: we can't help unless you post your code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

u can delete database manually by `clear Data`.

```
settings\applications\manage Applications\'select your application'\clear data.
```

Comment: this will delete more than the database.

Answer (score 9):

If you use `Room Persistence Library`, then try to do the following (but maybe it also will work for other libraries, I haven't checked).

In Android Studio open `View` -> `Tool Windows` -> `Device File Explorer`. Then in the Device File Explorer:

1. Choose your device.
2. In the file tree navigate to `/data/data/{your_package_name}/databases`.
3. Delete files which names match your database name (you give a name to your database when you build `RoomDatabase` in your code). In my case it's `my_app.db`.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: Here's a screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

There is a function to delete DB :

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#deleteDatabase(java.lang.String)

```
context.deleteDatabase(dbFileName)
```

It's that short...